# Filtering valueless get parameters

Tags: jquery, html, get

Assume I post a GET data via a form that has 3 selectbox elements:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?department=clothing&category=&brand=
```

How can I remove parameters which doesn't yield a value, such as: category and brand.

Comment: do you build that url? You can check if there is a value and don't add any parameter with no value.

Comment: I directly post the form by clicking the submit button and some of these elements have default options with empty values such as: <option value="">Choose one</option>

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Empty parameters should not have any effect on the data processing backend.

Comment: Also, how do you post a GET data?